# Python automatic web test tool with selenium: download file in firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, automated-tests, firefox-profile

I have a web test tool developed with python using selenium 3 api. I run it in Firefox. There's a part in the website permits to download a tar.gz file. I want that the test tool download the file in a specified local folder without displaying popup download window.
So in init step and before opening the browser I added some preferences to the profile of Firefox like that:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/x-gzip')
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloadPath)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
```

But this code doesn't prevent displaying the download window and always ask me where to download the file.

In addition if check preferences of Firefox while test running I find that Downloads setting is save to Downloads folder not like what is set in browser.download.dir parameter.

Is there any idea to fixe this problem?

Development environment: Python 2.7, selenium 3.0.1, Firefox 49

Comment: Could you try to use different `MIME`-type, like `application/x-gtar` or `application/tar+gzip`, `application/x-compressed`?

Comment: @Andersson I tried it :  profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/x-gzip, application/tar+gzip, application/x-gtar, application/x-compressed')
But ir didn't solve the problem